# SQL apply MAX to left join table having non null rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

table name: country

```
id country_name
1  USA
2  GERMANY
3  RUSSIA
```

table name: user

```
id user_name  points country_id
1  user1      20     1
2  user2      10     2
3  user3      11     2
```

Result should be country-user with maximum points and only country if no user available(3rd record),like below

```
country_name user_name points
USA          user1     20
GERMANY      user3     11
RUSSIA       (null)    (null)
```

Currently I am using below query but it is sometime taking too much time, like when i have 100000 records.

```
SELECT c.country_name,u.user_name,u.points FROM country c
LEFT JOIN user u on u.country_id = c.id 
WHERE (u.points = (SELECT MAX(points) AS points FROM user WHERE user.id = u.id) OR u.points IS NULL)
```

So, is there any other way to do it more efficiently, time-wise.

Thanks already!

Comment: The Oracle tag is more specific, so I'm guessing that you are using Oracle.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: sorry, wasn't able to add new tag because of reputation on stack overflow, i am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT c.country_name, u.user_name, u.points
FROM country c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT u.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.country_id ORDER BY u.points DESC) as seqnum
      FROM user u
      WHERE u.points IS NOT NULL
     ) u
     ON u.country_id = c.id AND u.seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  This returns one user per country, even if there are ties for the top one.  If you want all of them, use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works better in my case, the performance of query improves 234 sec to 2 sec, Thanks again.